# In search of a packaged .Net security solution for web-forms

Tags: asp.net, security

We are looking for a security solution for asp.net that has security down to the control level. This is not a necessity but, it would be nice. At the very least it needs to extend-able to allow for control level permissions.

The solution should have an administration panel of some sort. It also needs to support roles, groups, and individual permissions.

We haven't seen anything like this in the marketplace -- we are in the process of rolling our own solution. We'd rather use an off the shelf solution.

Comment: At first blush it looks like Windows Identity Foundation might be a partial solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Visual Guard will do what you want...(I haven't used it myself, i believe it is used in places within an organisation i work with)...It appears to have all the things you mentioned according to its features page (it does specifically mention being able to hide or disable controls, have an admin interface, users/roles/permissions etc).

http://www.visual-guard.com/EN

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wish I knew about this product a year ago. It's exactly what we needed.